# No output with speech_recognition python module

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am running the python module speech-recognition on mac

The system itself works (like no error appears) but there is no result output. I am speaking and there is no text.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

init_rec = sr.Recognizer()
print("Let's speak!!")
with sr.Microphone() as source:

    audio_data = init_rec.record(source, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing your text.............")
    text = init_rec.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

and heres the terminal

```
 % python3 voicerto.py   
Let's speak!!
Recognizing your text.............
```

thats it theres no text coming at all

I tried to change this line

```
audio_data = init_rec.record(source, duration=5)
```

to have duration 10 or 1

```
audio_data = init_rec.record(source, duration=10)

audio_data = init_rec.record(source, duration=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.record()`, I use `.listen()`, so try this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
print("Start speaking...")
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.pause_threshold = 1 #amount of time user can pause between speaking in seconds
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print(text)
```

And this should work. Don't know the difference between `.record()` and `.listen()`, but you should try this and see if it works. Otherwise, I recommend looking at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/).

EDIT:
It might be an internal thing, so I suggest that you check all your microphone devices, try this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
```

Comment: this doesn't work either... i have the same issue with pocketsphinx, vosk, and deepspeech

Comment: so it seems to be an internal thing, because other models result the same

Comment: Try checking all of your microphone devices (I have posted above) if you think it is an internal thing.